# Why this Cosmos Db query is better than a point read?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

After reading and watching infinite videos on Cosmos Db partitioning,
I sweared only on point reads.

In the NoSQL .Net SDK this translates to using `ReadItemAsync<T>`. But it seems I found a cheaper method and would like to know why that is expected, if it is expected.

Testing on the emulator, I have a container with a partition key path set to `/userId`. I have 200 documents representing a `User` poco. Each `User` is of the form :

```
public class User
{
    public User(string userId)
    {
        UserId = userId;
    }
    public required string Id { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public IList<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    public IList<Sale<Order, User>> Sales { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; } = nameof(User);
}
```

Importantly for what follows, each user has an average of 500 orders and 500 sales. I understand that I have to keep the documents lightweight, but I am testing. This results in an average document size of circa 120kB, so I believe this is still ok (<<2 MB).

More specifically, the app is designed such that I expect customers to do:

1. Rare reads of the entire `User` object (i.e. the complete document in the container)
2. More frequent reads of a part of the document, where I want only a view model of the `User`.

Thus, I have in addition the class:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

which essentially represents a view of the `User` class without the Orders and Sales and I focus only on the first name for testing.

**Question 1**

If I am interested only in the View Model to display it to the user, how I can ask Cosmos db **not** to return the entire `User` object to the web app (Asp.Net Core) but rather just do a selection on the cosmos db server and send me the View Model?

---

**Test 1**:
Listen to the Gods of Cosmos Db and do a point read by using as a Template the `UserViewModel`, i.e. do this

```
        var user = await _container.ReadItemAsync<UserViewModel>("fbea1444-8dcb-cb89-8cde-7adf8a580812", new PartitionKey("920a8e38-481a-3874-f14e-6de85029419f"));
```

The result of this point read on the logical partition gives

```
    "resource": {
      "firstName": "Reggie"
    },
    "statusCode": 200,
    "diagnostics": { },
    "requestCharge": 4.76
```

and if, instead, I cast to the `User`

```
   var user = await _container.ReadItemAsync<User>("fbea1444-8dcb-cb89-8cde-7adf8a580812", new PartitionKey("920a8e38-481a-3874-f14e-6de85029419f"));
```

I obtain of course the (huge) `User` as a resource, **but the request charge is the same, 4.76 RUs.**

**Question 2:** That the RU is the same, does this mean that Cosmos Db sends me back the entire object even if I use the first option, i.e. `UserViewModel`, and it is my web app which does the cast?

---

**Test 2: Where Clause on the partition userId**

In the hope of getting better, I abandoned the point read to use instead `GetItemLinqQueryable`

```
        // Get LINQ IQueryable object
        var queryable = _container.GetItemLinqQueryable<User>();

        // Construct LINQ query
        var matches = queryable
            .Where(b => b.UserId == "920a8e38-481a-3874-f14e-6de85029419f")
            .Select(u => new UserViewModel() { FirstName = u.FirstName });

        // Convert to feed iterator
        using var linqFeed = matches.ToFeedIterator();

        var totalCharge = 0.0;
        // Iterate query result pages
        while (linqFeed.HasMoreResults)
        {
            var response = await linqFeed.ReadNextAsync();
            result.Add($"Request Charge {response.RequestCharge} {totalCharge += response.RequestCharge} RUs");
            result.Add(response);
        }
```

```
  "Request Charge 3.03 3.03 RUs",
  [
    {
      "firstName": "Reggie"
    }
  ]
```

**Question 3**

Why this method (**3.03** RUs) is more efficient than a point read (**4.76** Rus)?

---

**Test 3 Where Clause on FirstName (not the parition key)**

From the above code, I also tested by using the Where clause on something else than the parition key property `UserId`, i.e.

```
        var matches = queryable
              .Where(b => b.FirstName == "Reggie")
              .Select(u => new UserViewModel() { FirstName = u.FirstName });
```

**Question 4**

The Request charge **is still 3.03 Ru**. Why is that?

---

**Test 4 Where clause with no Select**

```
        // Get LINQ IQueryable object
    var queryable = _container.GetItemLinqQueryable<UserViewModel>();

    // Construct LINQ query
    var matches = queryable
          .Where(b => b.FirstName == "Reggie");
```

**Question 5**

The Request charge **is now 3.8 RUs**. Why is it higher than the **3.03RUs**?

Adding a Select clause will allow me to get **3.03Rus**, whereas it does not make sense to have the Select clause given that I already use `UserViewModel` in `GetItemLinqQueryable`.

Note that I also tested by adding a UserId property to the ViewModel, thinking this is partition issue, and thus replaced the above where clause by `.Where(b=>b.UserId == "920a8e38-481a-3874-f14e-6de85029419f")`. But the request charge is the same, 3.8 Rus > 3.03 Rus.

These questions will allow me to understand how I can best ask the Cosmos Db servers to the job of sending me only the bits I need. My first test 1 above failed, and it seems the reason being that `ReadItemAsync<T>` does not ask Cosmos Db to "cast" on its server to send the much smaller `ViewModel` along the wire. Instead, what this method does, I believe, tests, is that it merely gets the entire document from Cosmos Db, and does the cast on my own app server.

Thank you

Comment: This is a fairly large question (actually a *lot* of questions), but... point-reads are going to return an entire document, where as with a query, you can do a projection, reducing bandwidth of returned payload. There's no rule that says a point-read will always cost less RU than a query, but it will cost less RU for an apples-to-apples comparison, where your query does a `SELECT *` based on id and partition key (if not `/id`) - the point-read doesn't invoke the query engine.

Comment: Sorry that there are many questions, but they are around the same problem and I tried to report on the different tests. regarding the apple-to-apples comparison, I get less Rus with the where clause than with the point read. So it does not seem true what you say in my case at least.

Comment: It is also not clear why the Select clause improves the Ru in the case where I already operate on the viewmodel (Question 5).

Comment: Probably would be much more helpful if your question showed the read vs actual query, instead of looking at the higher level LINQ.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. The Test 1 uses the read of known Id on a known partition key value. Ru = 4.76. I am happy to improve the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I obtain of course the (huge) User as a resource, but the request charge is the same, 4.76 RUs

The Model (type) is only used for deserialization, ReadItem will always return the entire document. If you have a Model that has less properties, the others will simply not get deserialized, but are part of the response.

> Why this method (3.03 RUs) is more efficient than a point read (4.76 Rus)?

Probably because the data volume is less, it's not a fair comparison because you are doing a projection on the query, thus reducing the volume of data that is returned from the service.

> The Request charge is now 3.8 RUs. Why is it higher than the 3.03RUs?

Your query is different, it is not filtering and thus processing and returning more data on the service.

Bottom line is, a ReadItem will be better than a SELECT * WHERE Id/PartitionKey, but if the documents are big, a SELECT `<single property>` WHERE Id/PartitionKey where the projection leaves out the big data properties, it might be cheaper because the volume of data is much lower.

Comment: Could you please confirm (or not) that the model type T, e.g in ReadItemAsync<T> or others such as GetItemLinqQueryable<T> and all other operations only means that there is deserialization on the app server and does not mean that Cosmos Db will do the filtering on its servers? Thank you

Comment: Correct. The model is purely an application concept that is used just for deserialization.

Comment: Your Bottom Line is incorrect, and maybe this isn’t the place but I’d love to know the answer. @octopus what are the RUs if you actually SELECT * on this? I’m just curious to see as my issue fits with your issue of strange RU metrics. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1193016/point-read-has-higher-rus-than-equivalent-query?page=1 Either something is wrong, or the entire Cosmos team need to stop lying about equivalent point reads vs queries being cheaper.

Comment: Rudi I remember that GetItemLinqQueryable is the best option to use if you project on view model. The point read returns the entire object from the cosmos db backend to the client. Using a select on GetItemLinqQueryable also works the same way, it is generally cheaper or at most equal to the point read. I hope this helps.